# Horizontal bounds not working in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
/*    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
    myLabel.text = "Hello, World!";
    myLabel.fontSize = 45;
    myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    self.addChild(myLabel)*/   let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Beach Ball-100")
    self.addChild(sprite)
    let bb = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    bb.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = bb

   }

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Beach Ball-100")
        self.addChild(sprite)

        sprite.xScale = 0.15
        sprite.yScale = 0.15

        sprite.position = location
        sprite.color = UIColor.redColor()
        //sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect:self.frame)
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 2.5)
        //sprite.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        sprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        sprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.5
        sprite.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        sprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        //self.physicsWorld.

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,-2.5)

        //self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.25, -0.25)
        //var action2 = SKAction.rotateByAngle(180.0, duration:5)
        //sprite.runAction( action2)
        //action = SKAction.applyTorque(2, duration: 3)
        //sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

        //let boundaries = UICollisionBehavior(items: [sprite])
    }
}
}
```

The horizontal boundaries don't seem to be working. If I drop the ball from the same point, since the friction is set to zero, they keep moving out of the screen. Please help me understand what the problem is.

Comment: What happens when the friction is not set to 0 (say, 0.5)?

Comment: How would setting the friction to 0.5 solve this problem?

Comment: From your description, it sounded like when you set it to 0, you started running into problems.  I was just wondering if the friction had something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because your scene size differs from a view's size. By default a scene is loaded from .sks file and it has size of 1024x768.

To fix this you can make these changes in your GameViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            //Make scene's size same as view's size
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what does the scaleMode property do?

Comment: @adf_mobile_developer scaleMode property defines how the scene is mapped to the view that presents it.

Comment: What does this mean?if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene

Comment: @adf_mobile_developer Ah...class func unarchiveFromFile is defined in a custom extension on SKNode in your view controller (in default SpriteKit project). But probably it's not there in the latest version of Xcode. And I guess that init(fileNamed:)  is used instead. Anyways, just set scene.size = skView.bounds.size and you will be fine.

Comment: the horizontal bound appears to be working now. But, the object seems to be going out of the vertical bound after adding an impulse and disabling the gravity. Any thoughts? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Also, how do I make sure that partial part of the object doesn't cross the border of the screen? I used anchorpoint but it is only helping with one of the borders i.e., either left or right

Comment: Does object goes out completely or just partially ? Turn on physics visual representation in your view controller : skView.showsPhysics = true. See if that helps with debugging. It might happen that bodies you have defined are smaller than actual images. Also you can print out scene's and view's size and update your question with that data. About anchor point...I am not sure that I fully understand you but...Anchor point is visual property and it doesn't affect on physics body position. Anchor point determines how texture is drawn relative to the node.

Comment: Is there an ideal size for the images that I use in swift? I don't know how to find out if the bodies are smaller than actual images. I will try enabling showsPhysics later today and try.

Comment: The size of scene and view are same i.e., (320.0,568.0)

Comment: The size of sprite node I am using is (19.7,17.35). I don't know how to get the size of the image I am using.

Comment: @adf_mobile_developer You will see if body is smaller than image by enabling visual physics representation in a view controller ;) It's a useful feature in development stage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94960/discussion-between-adf-mobile-developer-and-whirlwind).

Comment: Do you have any inputs? I am unable to debug even after enabling visual physics representation.

Comment: I modified the window size to 33% and it started working! Phew!